# Cannot get a already existing GUI to go into a JPanel in a resizable JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I have the following resizable form that consists of one main `JPanel` with 4 other `JPanel`s that go inside. They will resize as the `JFrame` is resized.

I decided to see if I could put another class that creates a GUI into the top frame that is depicted in the image below.

I think that it might be that I am trying to put a `JFrame` into a `JPanel` that is already in `JFrame`.

**Question: I want to put another GUI class (that makes a `JTable`) into a `JPanel` in another class?**

Code:

```
package testpak;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ResizeTestGUI {
  private JPanel jpPack;
  private JPanel jpCards;
  private JPanel jpInfo;
  private JPanel jpChat;
  private SimpleTableDemo std = new SimpleTableDemo();

  public ResizeTestGUI() throws MalformedURLException {
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Draft");
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel IsMainJPanel = new JPanel();
    IsMainJPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    jpCards = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    jpCards.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

    jpInfo = new JPanel();
    jpInfo.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

    jpPack = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    jpPack.setBackground(Color.RED);

    jpChat = new JPanel();
    jpChat.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH; // set it to fill both vertically and
                                      // horizontally
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.weightx = 0.3;
    c.weighty = 0.3;
    jpCards.add(std);
    IsMainJPanel.add(jpCards, c);

    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.weightx = 0.3;
    c.weighty = 0.3;
    IsMainJPanel.add(jpInfo, c);

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    c.weightx = 0.3;
    c.weighty = 0.3;
    IsMainJPanel.add(jpPack, c);

    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 1;
    c.weightx = 0.3;
    c.weighty = 0.3;
    IsMainJPanel.add(jpChat, c);

    frame.setContentPane(IsMainJPanel);
    frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
    frame.pack();

    frame.setExtendedState(frame.getExtendedState() | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
    ResizeTestGUI dg = new ResizeTestGUI();
  }
}
```

Simple JTable example: (found on internet)

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class SimpleTableDemo extends JPanel {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  private boolean DEBUG = false;

  public SimpleTableDemo() {
    super(new GridLayout(1, 0));

    String[] columnNames = { "First Name", "Last Name", "Sport", "# of Years",
        "Vegetarian" };

    Object[][] data = {
        { "Kathy", "Smith", "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false) },
        { "John", "Doe", "Rowing", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true) },
        { "Sue", "Black", "Knitting", new Integer(2), new Boolean(false) },
        { "Jane", "White", "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true) },
        { "Joe", "Brown", "Pool", new Integer(10), new Boolean(false) } };

    final JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
    table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

    if (DEBUG) {
      table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
          printDebugData(table);
        }
      });
    }

    // Create the scroll pane and add the table to it.
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

    // Add the scroll pane to this panel.
    add(scrollPane);
    createAndShowGUI();
  }

  private void printDebugData(JTable table) {
    int numRows = table.getRowCount();
    int numCols = table.getColumnCount();
    javax.swing.table.TableModel model = table.getModel();

    System.out.println("Value of data: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
      System.out.print("    row " + i + ":");
      for (int j = 0; j < numCols; j++) {
        System.out.print("  " + model.getValueAt(i, j));
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println("--------------------------");
  }

  /**
   * Create the GUI and show it. For thread safety, this method should be
   * invoked from the event-dispatching thread.
   */
  private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    // Create and set up the window.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("SimpleTableDemo");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    // Create and set up the content pane.
    SimpleTableDemo newContentPane = new SimpleTableDemo();
    newContentPane.setOpaque(true); // content panes must be opaque
    frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

    // Display the window.
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

[image]

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.Exception.<init>(Exception.java:102)
    at java.lang.ReflectiveOperationException.<init>(ReflectiveOperationException.java:89)
    at java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException.<init>(InvocationTargetException.java:72)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:75)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Sourc
```

Comment: Do you want to show the 2 JFrames at a time?

Comment: You haven't answered my question?

Comment: Well, I want to show the JFrame that has the GUI in the red JPanel. But not necessarily do I want to show the 2JFrames. But can you show two JFrames Lets say both had menues and you want to put them in each a jpanel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have created a **cyclic dependencies** of the object `SimpleTableDemo` as shown below that results into `StackOverflowError`

Constructor -> Method -> Constructor -> Method -> ...

```
public SimpleTableDemo() {
    super(new GridLayout(1, 0));

    ...
    createAndShowGUI();
}

private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    ...

    //Create and set up the content pane.
    SimpleTableDemo newContentPane = new SimpleTableDemo();
    ...
}
```

---

Do in this way

```
public SimpleTableDemo() {
    super(new GridLayout(1, 0));

    ...
    // pass the reference of this object
    createAndShowGUI(this);
}

private static void createAndShowGUI(SimpleTableDemo newContentPane ) {
    ...

    //remove this line
    //SimpleTableDemo newContentPane = new SimpleTableDemo();
    ...
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: That even puts the JFrame in the example?

Comment: I did get it to work if I took out the JFrame portion of the code and then just put the JPanel into the JPanel in red. Then it worked but your way would also allow for any menu on the JFrame to be displayed as well.